# Direct use of gstreamer-sharp (without command line)

Tags: c#, pipeline, gstreamer

I use gstreamer-sharp as follows:

```
var pipeDescription = "playbin uri=file:///a:/test.avi ";
var pipeline = Gst.Parse.Launch(pipeDescription) as Gst.Bin;
```

As far as I understand, it starts gstreamer's launcher and gives parameters to gstreamer. It is the same how I will launch gstreamer from the command line.

Is this the only choice to work with gstreamer? Can I use these functions, as in other libraries(`function();`), without indirectly using the command line? Is this possible for cross platform use if I use `gst-launch.exe`?

Comment: You mean create a pipeline without using Gst.Parse.Launch? What do you mean "functions" as in other libraries? And what do you mean use "gst-launch.exe"? Gstreamer in no way "indirectly uses the command line". It just parses a pipeline object that you can then use and play in a SIMILAR fashion to the command line launcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.Launch does not use the command line indirectly, it just behaves like gst-launch. You can also create an element using the ElementFactory and pass it the parameters like this:

```
var playbin = ElementFactory.Make("playbin", "my-playbin");
playbin["uri"] = "file:///a:/test.avi";
```